# Stream Analytics - query nested arrays returns 0 results

Tags: json, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

I have an array of messages; within each message is another array of start/stop values. I can get the array of messages fine, but getting the next level of nested start/stop values returns 0 records while executing a stream analytics query in Azure.

Here is the Stream Analytics query.

```
WITH 
main AS
(
    SELECT          message.ArrayValue.header.messageId,
                    message.ArrayValue.startStopBlock as SSBlock                    

    FROM            IoTHub i
    CROSS APPLY     GetArrayElements(i.[STARTSTOPTIME:topic].message) AS 
message
)

SELECT              m.messageId,               
                    SSEntry.ArrayValue.start,
                    SSEntry.ArrayValue.stop

FROM            main m
CROSS APPLY     GetArrayElements(m.SSBLOCK.ArrayValue.startStop) AS SSEntry
```

Here is the json

```js
{
 "@xsi:schemaLocation" : "",
 "nextBuffer" : {
  "url" : "",
  "moreData" : "false"
 },
 "message" : [{
   "header" : {
    "messageId" : "951262328",
   },
   "totalStartStops" : "2",
   "startStopBlock" : {
    "startStop" : [{
      "start" : "2017-05-16 14:11:01",
      "stop" : "2017-05-16 14:14:16",
      "operatorId" : "0"
     }, {
      "start" : "2017-05-16 14:38:45",
      "stop" : "2017-05-16 14:44:19",
      "operatorId" : "0"
     }
    ]
   }
  }, {
   "header" : {
    "messageId" : "951266462",
   },
   "totalStartStops" : "2",
   "startStopBlock" : {
    "startStop" : [{
      "start" : "2017-05-16 14:08:09",
      "stop" : "2017-05-16 14:08:20",
      "operatorId" : "-1"
     }, {
      "start" : "2017-05-16 14:54:38",
      "stop" : "2017-05-16 15:01:17",
      "operatorId" : "-1"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, you could try to retrieve the nested arrays in your first query by changing `message.ArrayValue.startStopBlock as SSBlock` to `message.ArrayValue.startStopBlock.startStop as SSBlock`. Here is my test, you could refer to it:

**Query**

```html
WITH main AS
(
    SELECT  
      message.ArrayValue.header.messageId,
      message.ArrayValue.startStopBlock.startStop as SSBlock                    
    FROM IoTHub i
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(i.message) AS message
)

SELECT
  m.messageId,               
  SSEntry.ArrayValue.start,
  SSEntry.ArrayValue.stop
FROM main m
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(m.SSBLOCK) AS SSEntry
```

**Result**
[image]